# How do I convert a n*1 matrix to a n*n diagonal matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a nx1 matrix I want to convert this to a nxn diagonal matrix in R

[image: matrix transformation]

Comment: bison, google the identity matrix, and you should delete this question, it doesnt look like it belongs to this site

Comment: The question isn't clear. If you want to know how to do this w/ software, you would needto specify the language (& this Q would belong on  stack Overflow). If you want to know how to multiply, etc, that vector to get the result, this Q belongs on math.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Ben Bolker has suggested, you can simply define your identity matrix using `diag`:

```
my.matrix <- diag(0.25, 4)
my.matrix
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,] 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
## [2,] 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00
## [3,] 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00
## [4,] 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
```

Comment: Thanks Maetheran, it turned out to be a simple one line step, thanks again for your help you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to know how to do this in `R`, it's:

```
my.matrix       <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=4)
diag(my.matrix) <- rep(0.25, 4)
```

Comment: or more generally `diag(c(orig_column_vector))`

Answer (score 2):

In your case, where the original vector contains identical elements, it suffices to multiply the **n** x **n** Identity matrix by **0.25** as the comments suggested.

But the general case of a vector with non-identical elements is more interesting:

Denote your **n** x **1** column vector by **v** = (v_1,...,v_n)'. 
Then, define the **n** x **n** matrix **E_i** as a matrix having **1** in its [i,i] element and zeros everywhere else. Also define the **n** x **1** column vector **e_i** as a vector having **1** in the [i] position (row) and zeros everywhere else.

Then the **n** x **n** matrix **V** = **diag**(v_1,...,v_n) can be obtained as

### **V** = **Σ**(**E_i v** **e_i**')

where the sum is over **i=1,...n**

Answer (score 0):

Ya got a ton of rude and/or not so general answers here, so I figured I'd give you a new one. My professor and I distinguish `diag()` and `Diag()` differently, where `diag()` converts a matrix to a vector and `Diag()` converts a vector into a diagonal matrix. Lucky for you, `diag()` is already in R. So we just have to make something for `Diag()`. For that I've created the following function:

```
Diag <- function(vec){
  diag_matrix = diag(c(vec))
  return(diag_matrix)
}
```

Now keep in mind, this assumes that your vector in R is an nx1, meaning that it's not already an actual R vector, but rather an R matrix with n rows and 1 column. But if I understand what you're asking correctly, this should take care of it. Just...you know, 10 years too late. Maybe someone can use it though!